# Windows 10 unique signature

Tags: windows

I'm intending to use a combination of a Windows 10 unique signature and account to identify my app' user so that they cannot use multiple account on a same Windows installation even when they remove everything from my app and reinstall.

Is there a signature of Windows 10 that will **CHANGE only after reinstall windows**?

I have read many threads that suggest using the MachineGUID registry, but this value can be changed by user. Are there any other cannot be changed by user?

Update: In case someone else bought the computer and reinstall windows, I want them to be able to use the app, that's why I need the signature to only change after reinstall windows.

Comment: I would use a combination of hw id's (cpu, ram, gpu) that is almost the same but do not relay on the Mac Adress. it can be faked, easily. We did that for a updater to know how many used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have read many threads that suggest using the MachineGUID registry, but this value can be changed by user. Are there any other cannot be changed by user?

Fundamentally, no. Users are in control of their hardware. They can change any and all data on the hard drive. The data that cannot be changed, such as serial numbers, are likely to stay the same across installs.

Furthermore, it's probably trivial to modify your app to bypass such an restriction. What you propose is fundamentally DRM, and noone has yet conjured up a scheme that isn't broken in every imaginable way.